# Access tag is not a synonym for ms-access

Tags: support, status-completed

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access

I am not sure why [access](/questions/tagged/access) has been added to the [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag as a synonym. Access applies to multiple situations - disk access, facebook access, etc.

Comment: But is there really a scenario where it makes *sense* other than in the context of Microsoft Access?

Comment: Is there any reason why people looking for ms-access should be plagued with totally irrelevant questions and answers?

Comment: When I read this, I expected people to be confusing "access" with "accessibility" (e.g. "How can I access Windows's color scheme settings to accomodate vision-impaired users?"). A quick check shows that this isn't an issue in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the synonym.  The term "access" can mean any number of things besides ms-access, and co-opting it for Microsoft Access doesn't make sense to me.

(note to self: [access](/questions/tagged/access) isn't the best of tags.)